# How do I find whose Windows authentication being used in existing connection string?

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

One of our previous developer created an ADO.NET connection string in a SSIS package with `integrated security = true` and that is working fine in production, but where can I see which user's Windows authentication is being used in that connection string?

Comment: Whichever Windows user is logged on when running this SSIS package, or whichever Windows account this package is being scheduled to run (if you're using e.g. Windows Task Scheduler to run it)

Comment: Thanks marc..I was talking about "source server Connection"  that was being created by previous developer with parameter integrated security=true , I need to know what user id  will be used when attempting source database. Where does that information being stored?

Comment: It's not *being stored* anywhere - the **currently logged in user's credentials** are used - unless you're running the process under a defined, configured other user/system account......

Comment: thanks again marc, let me put my question this way..first the user X logged into Visual Studio and create the connection string to connect Source database server with Integrated Security=True that means , X would have had Windows Authentication to connect source database..everything working fine..he deployed ssis package into SSIDB catalog and create the job and scheduled once a day and working fine. now X left the company. now Y joined and imported ssis package into Visual Studio and he wanted to check X credentials means what is X userID and is X password will expire etc..is that possible?

Comment: So when X created and tested the package, the connection string was using X's Windows credentials. WHen later on Y now runs the package, the connection string is using Y's Windows credentials. There's **nothing** being **stored** or **cached** - the connection string just simply uses **whatever CURRENT user** and his/her credentials as he runs the package.

Comment: the job was scheduled and it's been running for few months, now Y wanted to see which credentials being used in this job as he doesn't who developed and who scheduled this job and who's windows credentials currently job is using to connect source database